# Inserting multiple array values in mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have two PHP variables, both strings:

```
$friendslist = "2323443,7245,284683,345123,8456234,95432"

$id = "10288272";
```

The structure of the table I am concerned with is as follows:

Table Name: UserLinks

```
link_id   user_1    user_2
```

I need to insert these values into the table so that user_1 is always $id, and user_2 is the members of the $friendslist string. It will look like this:

```
link_id   user_1    user_2
1         10288272  2323443
2         10288272  7245
3         10288272  284683
4         10288272  345123
```

I know the basics of inserting many values, where in this cause I would use:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO UserLinks (User_1, User_2) VALUES ('10288272','2323443'),('10288272','7245'),('10288272','284683')");
```

But the only way I can think to of to write this (as these values are obviously not the actual values inserted) is something like this:

```
$friendarray = explode(",", $friendslist);

for ($n = 0; $n < count($friendarray); $n++) {
      $friendidpush = "('".$id."','".$friendarray[$n]."'),";
      array_push($frienduserarray, $friendidpush);
}
```

Followed by converting the $frienduserarray to a string, and then including it in my query. This returned an error for me, and I do not think this is the right way to do it... but I am struggling to find a solution online.

Comment: Warning:  array_push() First argument should be an array

Comment: not sure if this is even a good way to do this, though :/

Comment: thank you below! yes it needed to be initialized properly... my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't initialising `$frienduserarray` as an array, so `array_push` doesn't work.

```
$friendarray = explode(",", $friendslist);
$frienduserarray = array();

for ($n = 0; $n < count($friendarray); $n++) {
      $friendidpush = "('".$id."','".$friendarray[$n]."'),";
      array_push($frienduserarray, $friendidpush);
}
```

Note that this seems to be complicating things to me.  Why is the second array even necessary? Just use string concatenation.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO UserLinks (User_1, User_2) VALUES ";
$friendarray = explode(",", $friendslist);

foreach ($friendarray as $friend) {
    $query .= "('" . $id . "','" . $friend . "'),";
}

$query = substr($query, 0, -1); // remove trailing comma

mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: ah I see. I am still wondering if this is a good way to do this? I will continue if so !

Comment: Col. Shrapnel your answer is great too!

Answer (score 3):

```
$comma  = "";
$values = "";
$array  = explode(",",$friendslist);
foreach ($array as $friendid) {
  $values .= $comma."($id,$friendid)";
  $comma = ",";
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO UserLinks (User_1, User_2) VALUES $values"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you have not declared the `$frienduserarray` as array any where in your code. Just declare it

```
 $frienduserarray=array();
```

before the `for` loop. After that your code should look like

```
  $friendarray = explode(",", $friendslist);
  $frienduserarray=array();
  for ($n = 0; $n < count($friendarray); $n++) {
      $friendidpush = "('".$id."','".$friendarray[$n]."'),";
      array_push($frienduserarray, $friendidpush);
  }
```