# Insert multiple values to the same table field

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I'm trying to add multiple fields to the same table. when i do echo $url, i can see the url values, but the data is not getting stored for all urls, it's the first url only.

example, a company website can have multiple urls.

```
foreach ($_POST['url'] as $url) {
   //$url = $_POST['url'];
    echo $url;
    $sql_insert_url="insert into url_table(url, company_name) 
          values ('$url', '$comp_name')";
}
```

my html:

```
<div id="allurl">
        <div id="newurl">
            <label for="companyurl" >Company URL #1</label>
            <input type="text" name="url[]" id="url" maxlength="300" />
            <input type='button' value='Add' id='addurl' />
            </p>
        </div>
```

javascript:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var counter=2;
    $("#addurl").click(function(){


        var n= $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'newurl' + counter);

        n.after().html('<p><label>Company URL #' + counter + ' </label>' + '<input type="text" name="url[]" value="url' + counter + '" id="url' + counter + '" value="" />' + '<input type="button" name="remove'  +'" id="removeurl' +  '" value="Remove" /></p>');
        n.appendTo("#allurl");
        counter++;

    });
```

any help with this will be appreciated. also, please suggest some good php editor that will help me figure out the php bugs, memory leaks etc quickly.

Comment: where do you execute the query?

Comment: Your `foreach` loop keeps assigning the same variable each time through. At the end of the loop, `sql_insert_url` will only contain the value from the last URL, the other URLs are ignored.

Comment: when i do echo $url; i can see all the urls, but when it comes to inserting to table it only inserts the last url. My table had (url_id auto_increment PK, url varchar, company_name varchar)

Comment: Where do you execute the SQL? If you execute it inside the loop, it should insert all of them. If you execute it outside the loop, I explained why you only get the last one.

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT` allows multiple sets of values after the `VALUES` keyword. This code combines all the URLs into a list of like this:

```
$values = implode(',', array_map(function($x) use ($comp_name) {
    return "('" . mysql_real_escape_string($x) . "', '$comp_name')"; },
  $_POST['url']));
$sql_insert_url = "insert into url_table(url, company_name) values $values";
```

Comment: Missing comma between the arguments to `implode`, I fixed it.

Comment: No luck yet. i get the last one with my code. this code is not working for me.

Comment: insert into url_table(url, company) values ('', 'truturet'),('', 'truturet'),('', 'truturet')  no values for url

Comment: What SQL API are you using? My answer assumed you're using the mysql_XXX extension, and that you've already opened the connection. If not, you need to replace `mysql_real_escape_string()` with the analogous function for the extension you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:
     [Inserting multiple array values in mySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818570/inserting-multiple-array-values-in-mysql-database)

```
so all i needed to do is 
    $sql = "insert into win_url(url, company) values";
        foreach ($_POST['url'] as $url) {
         $sql .=  "('".$url."','" . $comp_name. "'),";

           }

     $sql = substr($sql, 0, -1); // remove trailing comma
      mysql_query($sql);

that's it.. magic... it works. thanks to me. i'm the best.
```