# Inserting values of array into MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a text file, who's value i have put into arrays,
this is the php code:

```
<?php
    $homepage = file_get_contents('hourlydump.txt');
    $x = explode('|', $homepage);
    $desc = array();
    $cat = array();
    $link = array();
    $m = 1;
    $n = 2;
    $p = 3;

    for ($i = 1; $i <= count($x) / 4; $i++) {
       $m = $m + 4;
       $desc[] = $x[$m];
       $n = $n + 4;
       $cat[] = $x[$n];
       $p = $p + 4;
       if ($x[$p])
          $link[] = $x[$p];
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($desc);
    print_r($cat);
    print_r($link);
?>
```

output is like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Kamal Heer - Facebook Official Video 720p Dual Audio [Hindi + Punjabi]76 mb by rANA.mkv
    [1] => 50 HD Game Wallpapers Pack- 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => Movies
    [1] => Other
)
Array
(
    [0] => http://kickass.to/kamal-heer-facebook-official-video-720p-dual-audio-hindi-punjabi-76-mb-by-rana-mkv-t7613070.html
    [1] => http://kickass.to/50-hd-game-wallpapers-pack-1-t7613071.html
)
//
//
//
```

anyone please help me i dont know how to insert the values of these three arrays $desc, $cat and $link
into mysql table, columns named description, category, link

i know simple insert queries but dont how to deal with these arrays.

Comment: Refer this link it may help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818570/inserting-multiple-array-values-in-mysql-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple sample to read your file as is from the website you retrieve it as well as inserting it to the database sanitizing the data:

```
<?php
// fill with your data
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = '';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = '';
$db_table = 'myTable';

$file = "hourlydump.txt.gz";
if($filehandle = gzopen($file, "r"))
{
    $content = gzread($filehandle, filesize($file));
    gzclose($file);
}
else
    die('Could not read the file: ' . $file);

$con = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_name);
if($con->connect_error)
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());

$sql = "INSERT INTO $db_table (description, category, link) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
if (!$insert = $con->prepare($sql))
    die('Query failed: (' . $con->errno . ') ' . $con->error);

foreach (explode("\n", $content) as $line)
{
    list($md5hash,$desc,$cat,$link,$torrent) = explode("|", $line);
    if (!$insert->bind_param('sss',$desc,$cat,$link))
        echo 'Binding parameters failed: (', $insert->errno, ') ', $insert->error;

    if (!$insert->execute())
        echo 'Insert Error ', $insert->error;
}

$insert->close();
$con->close();
```

NOTE: you may want to check if the file was loaded with success, if the fields from the explode exist or not to prevent further problems but in general this should work just fine.

Also you may want to change the `$sql` to reflect your MySQL table aswell as the `$db_table` at the top.

UPDATE: to insert all values change this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $db_table (description, category, link) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
```

To:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $db_table (md5, description, category, link, torrent) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ? ,?)";
```

And this:

```
if (!$insert->bind_param('sss',$desc,$cat,$link))
```

To:

```
if (!$insert->bind_param('sssss',$md5hash,$desc,$cat,$link,$torrent))
```

Note above the `s` for each item you need a `s` you have 5 items so 5 `s`'s the S means string, D double, I integer, B blob [you can read more at about it here.](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Also note the `$sql` for each item we will use on the `bind_param` we have a `?`.

Comment: one more thing...
this code is working fine... for inserting those three values.... 
but when i am trying to insert all five values... it is showing error as

Query failed: (1136) Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
 Any ideas...?

Comment: I tried that but it says...
Insert Error Column 'torrent' cannot be null

Comment: @YugeshMLuv that means that row on your file does not have a value for torrent. it does not stop inserting the other results it will just skip to the next one if a field does not exist. After the line `list($md5hash,$desc,$cat,$link,$torrent) = explode("|", $line);` add this `echo $desc, " - ", $torrent, "\n";` and you will know where it had no `$torrent` value and will as well see the progress.

Comment: thanks a lot.... i enabled null value in my database... and it worked perfectly... :)

Comment: Hey... I have came up across another issue....
this above query is working perfectly with small amount of data... but when i am trying to process bigger amount of data.. its giving me trouble..
it inserts the data till the 2461 rows... after that it stops... i tried deleting  that row to see if it have some problematic data... then it stopped after 2462nd row...
you have any idea whats wrong...?
i tried to change the max execution time and max allowed packet data nothing really worked... the problem remains the same...

Comment: Post a new question with your current issue, table structure, error message you get when it fails and drop me a comment with the link and I will give it a look.

Answer (score 4):

I will give you an example of how basic database connection is made and the insert is completed, this is for illustrative purpose only. You should reorganize this code inside a class so that every insert statement doesn't create a PDO object but re-use the object created before.

```
 function insertItem($desc, $cat, $link) {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=host;dbname=db", $user, $pass);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (description, category, link) VALUES (:desc, :cat, :link)";

    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->bindValue(":desc", $desc);
    $sth->bindValue(":cat", $cat);        
    $sth->bindValue(":link", $link);
    $sth->execute();
  }
```

Comment: **+1** for not being vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for statement.

```
 for($x =0, $num = count($desc); $x < $num; $x++){
     // build you query 
     $sql = "INSERT into your_table (description, category, link) values ".
            "(".$db->quote($desc[$x]).",".$db->quote($cat[$x]).",".
                $db->quote($link[$x].")";
     $db->query($sql);
 }
```

Of course you will have to use the sanitation/quoting methods appropriate for your chosen database api.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I am assuming that only these much of values are there for insertion

```
for($i = 0;$i<2;$++) {
mysqli_query("INSER INTO tablename values(description,category,link) VALUES('$desc[$i]'
,'$cat[$i]','$link[$i]')");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build your query while you're doing you calculations:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `table` (`description`, `category`, `link`) VALUES ";
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($x) / 4; $i++) {
   $m = $m + 4;
   $query .= "('".$x[$m];
   $n = $n + 4;
   $query .= "','".$x[$n];
   $p = $p + 4;
   if ($x[$p]) $query .= "','".$x[$p]."'),";
   else $query .= "',NULL),";
}
$query = substr($query, 0, -1);//get rid of last comma
mysqli_query($query);
```

You can also build the arrays along with the query if you need to:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `table` (`description`, `category`, `link`) VALUES ";
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($x) / 4; $i++) {
   $m = $m + 4;
   $desc[] = $x[$m];
   $query .= "('".$x[$m];
   $n = $n + 4;
   $cat[] = $x[$n];
   $query .= "','".$x[$n];
   $p = $p + 4;
   if ($x[$p]){
       $link[] = $x[$n];
       $query .= "','".$x[$p]."'),";
   } else {
       $link[] = $x[$n];
       else $query .= "',NULL),";
}
$query = substr($query, 0, -1);//get rid of last comma
mysqli_query($query);
```

Answer (score -1):

make the array to a string

```
$description = json_encode($desc);
$category = json_encode($cat);
$link = json_encode($link);
```

then insert these values to database

At the time of fetching

Use `json_decode` to get the array again from the string