# Read array and write to txt file

Tags: php, arrays, file

I've an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
       (
        [name] => post
        [fql_result_set] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [post_id] => value
                        [message] => value
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [post_id] => value
                        [message] => value
                    )

       )
)
```

I want to write array to file, something like:

```
post_id = value;
message = value;

-----

post_id = value;
message = value;
```

I know that for write I can use:

```
    file_put_contents('file.txt', print_r($array[0], true));
```

but I need to do a "parsing"... how can I do this? 
Can someone help me please?
Sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: That's not "parsing". That's just "traversing" the array structure. You need a [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) loop, starting at `$array[0]["fql_result_set"]`.

Comment: By `parsing` do you mean you wish to `parse` the information saved? `post_id = value;`, `message = value;`, etc.

Comment: I mean that I need to parse information BEFORE save it, in the form specified form..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `for`:

```
<?php
$result = $data[0]['fql_result_set'];
$total = count($result);
for ($i=0; $i < $total; $i++)
{
    echo "post_id = ", $result[$i]['post_id'], "\n";
    echo "message = ", $result[$i]['message'], "\n";
    echo "------------------------\n";
}
```

Or a `foreach`:

```
$result = $data[0]['fql_result_set'];
foreach ($result as $outer)
{
    foreach ($outer as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $key, " = ", $value, "\n";
    }
    echo "------------------------\n";
}
```

**[Live DEMO.](https://eval.in/40486)**

Saving to file by appending it to the end:

```
$file = 'file.txt';
$result = $data[0]['fql_result_set'];
foreach ($result as $outer)
{
    foreach ($outer as $key => $value)
    {
        file_put_contents($file, "{$key} = {$value}\r\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    }
    file_put_contents($file, "----\r\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
```

[**Append to the end of the file using FILE_APPEND and LOCK_EX flag to prevent anyone from accessing the file until we're done writing.**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: Thanks this works, but with echo I print on screen, to write in a file every line what I need to do? String concatenation for each row?

Comment: @user2396911 that depends do you want to overwrite the file with the new data or do you want to append the data to the end ?

Comment: Before FOR I always delete file and re-create.
But I want to append each row to the new file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works :)
One other thing: I need to insert this data in a MySQL Database (not in the php server), do you thinks that export to .txt in this format is the best way to do this? Any suggest? Thanks.

Comment: @user2396911 That depends on your circumstances can you not do it directly from the array as it is ?

Comment: How can i write a local db from php page?

Comment: @user2396911 here is a simple example you could use with the above code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691354/inserting-values-of-array-into-mysql/17691707#17691707 give it try and if u can't make it make a new question about the issue you're having.

Comment: Ok thanks. Last thing: in your examples, I've added ."\r\n" to insert new line for each row, but how can I add "-----" for every "block"?

Comment: @user2396911 don't worry about saving it to a file, worry about making the MySQL connection and inserting it directly to the database if that is your goal there is no point saving it to a file to later put it on the db.

Comment: @user2396911 With the above code you already know how to traverse the array, now you just need to connect to the database and insert the data :)